# How do I remove a string from a variable using JS in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

Currently I have a variable: "Your temporary password is: av9GhRN59O".
I need the variable to become "av9GhRN59O". How do I go about doing this inside Selenium IDE?

Comment: In more general terms, are you saying you want to delete everything before the final word? (Or could some other hypothetical data have additional words after the bit you care about, like "Your temporary password is: av9GhRN59PO. Do not lose it.")

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do.
The temp password is dynamic, but I'm unable to grab ONLY the password from the page, without the rest of the string - which is why I want to remove everything before the final word.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
store | Your temporary password is: av9GhRN59O | string

store | 1 | delimiter

store | javascript{storedVars['string'].split('password is: ')[storedVars['delimiter']]} | password
```